# Find duplicate values in a block of cells

Tags: excel

is there any way (formulas or vba) to find if a range of cells is repeated in the same sheet? I'll try to explain myself better with an example - say I have:

```
  A  B  C
1 x  x  x
2 y  y  y
3 z  z  z
4
5 x  x  x
6 y  y  y
7 z  z  z
```

In this case if I want to look for range A1:C3 it should tell me that range A5:C7 is a duplicate of the first range.

Data in the different ranges will have the same order so it should look at range1 = range2

Comment: Are the ranges dynamic or are they set? For example is it always testing if A1:C3 matches A5:C7, if not than a formula will not work.  Formulas need patterns to do this.

Comment: @ScottCraner ranges will be dynamic but if a Formula would make it easier than VBA I could change the ranges each time. I have started writing some VBA code: 
`Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    For Each cel In rng
        Debug.Print cel.Value
    Next cel`

Comment: How many ranges are you likely to have? This could get very complicated.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:C3=A5:C7))=ROWS(A1:C3)*COLUMNS(A1:C3)`

Comment: @SJR it can be several ranges. Unfortunately I know it can get very complicated.

Comment: @ScottCraner it is a good start, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA approach, just a set of boring old loops really so it may not be optimally efficient.

Some caveats

- it will stop as soon as it finds the same range (even if there are other repeats), though could change this
- it doesn't look for subsets (i.e. a range being duplicated within a large range
- it is based on your cells not containing formulas, but again could be changed if this is not the case.

  ---

  ```
  Sub x()

  Dim rng As Range, r As Range, n As Long, b As Boolean

  Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

  For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
      If r.Address <> rng.Address And r.Rows.Count = rng.Rows.Count And r.Columns.Count = rng.Columns.Count Then
          For n = 1 To r.Count
              If r.Cells(n).Value <> rng.Cells(n).Value Then
                  b = True
                  Exit For
              End If
          Next n
          If Not b Then
              MsgBox "Cells " & r.Address & " are the same as selected range (" & rng.Address & ")"
          End If
          Exit Sub
      End If
  Next r

  End Sub
  ```

[image]